# How to add new property to an object at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, properties

In C# we can use something like this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.Properties.Add("another property", "another value");
```

I need to do this in C++. I'm using VS 2012. Any ideas?

**Edited**: Know, that I can use map, or any list to save property to object, like:

```
void ObjectProperty::addItem(string key, XProperty p) 
{
     _object[key] = p;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just add "properties" to objects -- the concept of an object is done completely at compile time. At run time, the CPU doesn't know that a given block of memory is called an "object" or whatever you decided to call an instance of a class.

(This in and of itself is kind of interesting because C++ does not have properties)

If you just want a data field that you refer to by name, any of the standard associative containers should do what you need.